# Is it legal to practice psychotherapy between different U.S. states via electronic media?

Tags: health

Are there any laws against practicing psychotherapy across state lines via electronic media?

Comment: Pay in cash and anything is likely possible.

Answer (score 1):

My psychologist in MN said they could do it, but insurance requires you to physically be in the same state.

Answer (score 0):

There would be a licensing problem.  Find a therapist you can actually visit would be my suggestion, and purely a personal opinion.